# Закрывашка вопросов "Вопрос вызван неумением или нежеланием читать документацию"

Tags: обсуждение

Простите, наболело.

> Вопрос вызван неумением или нежеланием **читать документацию**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Ознакомьтесь с официальной документацией по языку программирования, фреймворку, библиотеке или програмному обеспечению, которое вы используете, прежде чем задать вопрос.

Как вам предложение?

Comment: так под это львиная доля вопросов подходит, большинство задач можно разбить на атомарные, указания для решения которых можно найти в документации

Comment: Если вопрос - дубликат документации, например "Что передавать во второй параметр функции qsort?", то на сайте он очевидно не нужен. Можно как минимум смело минусовать, даже если нет такой причины закрытия. Но мне кажется проблему более представляют те, которые дубликаты задачника про программированию за 1 курс, а не документации...

Comment: зато закрыли бы сразу все вопросы по регулярным выражениям - ведь любой регекс можно написать, если тщательно прочитать документацию :)

Comment: Рекорд по минусам на SO за 1 пост побит. :) Давайте еще.

Comment: Без обид, но идея поинтлесс, смысл SO в создании своей документации по всем вопросам, поэтому мы тут часто бываем чаще, чем в доках ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Да какие обиды, это пост был весь в минусах еще до того как я его написал. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В вопросах предполагающих отсылку к документации - имхо, нет ничего плохого, ведь на такие вопросы можно дать полезный ответ:

- копипастом из документации, с гиперссылкой на источник
- написав перевод доков / более подробное их изложение / пример или алгоритм решения (то есть, какое-либо разъяснение уже *в контексте задачи вопроса* и **ru**SO - а не в общем контексте, как в документации).

Почему такие вопросы допустимы, и почему допустимо копировать информацию из справочных материалов: потому что целью SO является создание базы знаний: тут мы собираем знания в одном месте.
Первый же вопрос предполагающий копирование документации, автоматически становится "каноничным": как только появится ответ с копипастой, последующие (аналогичные) вопросы можно будет закрывать дубликатом, и через некоторое время они будут автоматически удалены (так и автор с остальным сообществом получают ответ, и база не засоряется).

Конечно, для сообщества наиболее полезны вопросы и ответы связанные с **конкретной** практической задачей - той, которую документация предполагает, но не рассматривает явно.
Если же в вопросе конкретной задачи нет, и непонятно о чем именно спрашивается, то вместо копирования *всей* документации (или целой ее главы) уместнее закрытие с уже существующей причиной "Непонятна суть вопроса".

---

Таким образом, приходим к следующим выводам:

- предлагаемая причина закрытия - не нужна
  *// потому что она противоречит цели SO, плюс крайне вероятно что такой причиной будут злоупотреблять (см. [обоснование в комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11695/#comment50306_11695))*
- нужно ли закрывать те вопросы, ответом на которые является документация - только когда смысл вопроса слишком размыт, и не вносится улучшающих правок
  *// копировать всю документацию - не очень разумно (т.к. качество ответа во многом зависит от его конкретики/однозначности)*
- выразить свое отношение к лени автора самостоятельно почитать документацию и/или поэкспериментировать - можно минусом
  *// Если посмотреть тултип кнопки <kbd>▼</kbd>, первая из причин там: "Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; ..." (случай нежелания читать доки, к этой причине вполне подходит).*

Comment: Вот. Хорошой исчерпывающий пост. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Уже кучу раз обсуждалось, что такие вопросы - онтопик.

Надо только чтобы они были заданы конкретно, а не включали обвязку из всего от написать программу, считать, вывести и вообще.

Comment: Скучный, душный модеротор. :) Я не настолько болен на голову, чтобы предлагать такое улучшение всерьёз. Очевидно, что даже если бы очень хотелось, отсечь эту категорию вопросов достаточно проблематично. Не всякая документация (например от майкрософт) вообще читабельна для нормальных людей, а тем более для новичков. Именно поэтому стоит метка "Обсуждение", а не "Предложение". Можете удалить пост, если считаете нужным.

Comment: @aepot метка может и "обсуждение", но в тексте "предложение". Хотя даже это по сути не имеет значения. У вас одно мнение, у кого-то другое. Это нормально.

Comment: Если кучу раз обсуждалось, можно бы и скинуть ссылку на хотя бы один дубликат.